# How can I enable retweets?

Tags: twitter, package, umbraco

I downloaded and checked so I dont show retweets. But I kinda want them, how do I change this? And the other settings too would be nice.

I've tried looking at the xslt file but it seems just to call the macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `include_rts` to true in your REST calls to get retweets.